# User/group - folders mapping on Windows SBS 2008

Tags: windows, permissions, small-business

How can I know which files/folders are accessible by a specific user/group on Windows SBS 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions are stored on the file or folder itself. The only way to get a report of what a user or group can access is to write a script that opens the Access Control List on each resource and checks for that name or group. It must also check for groups that the user or group is a member of. It's not a simple task and often third party tools are utilized for this. It can also take several days to run if there are a lot of files.